Efficient Configurations for Solving CNF Formulae with Z3 SMT Solver
I'm using the Z3 SMT solver and noticed varying efficiencies with different tactics and strategies for CNF formulae across problem domains. Could anyone share about 5 efficient configurations (strategies/tactics) commonly used with Z3?
Thanks!

No such thing, unfortunately. The tactics you use would be extremely problem specific. You need to tell us more about the kind of problem you’re solving for any relevant advice. (Even then, it’ll most likely be trial-and-error, unless it’s a well studied problem.)

I completely agree with you. Indeed, there can be numerous variations of configurations considering the acceptable values for each parameter, which could be Boolean, integer, and so forth. However, not all combinations of these assignments may be valid. My objective is to generate as many configurations as possible, provided they are logical and applicable, even if it's for a single problem domain. For instance, I aim to construct a comprehensive set of configurations, each of which could be suitable for solving problems in the SAT competition or any problem in any other domain.

Given all that, the question than is rather moot. There's no such thing as N-efficient-configurations for any N.
